Export Data Laravel Excel
I want to perform an export to totalize certain values.
My tables -> Services, Accounts, Profiles that are related to each other.
A Service has several accounts, an account has several profiles, a profile has a subscription
I need to generate 2 types of reports, in the first type of report I need to generate a table that separates the accounts by service, or that groups them in some way that allows to separate them. I have managed to generate the report but I can not separate the data by service.
My accountsExport Controller
public function view(): View
    {
        return view('admin.accounts.excel', [
            'services' => Service::all()->groupBy('1'),
            'accounts' => Account::where('status',1)->where('dateto', '<=' ,now()->addDays(4))->orderBy('service_id')->get(),

        ]);
    }

My Excel accountExport Blade
<div class="container" >
    <h1 >ACCOUNTS  REPORT</h1>

</div>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Service</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Expiration</th>
            <th>Last Days</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        @foreach($accounts as $account)

            <tr>
                <td width="20">{{ $account->service->name }}</td>
                <td width="35">{{ $account->email }}</td>
                <td width="13">{{ $account->password }}</td>
                <td width="10">{{ $account->pais }}</td>
                <td width="20">{{ $account->dateto }}</td>
                <td width="10">{{ $account->last_days }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

This gives me an excel file with this view
But what I want to get is this
I don't know how to make them separate and group them by Service
=====================================================================
My second Report
Each account has a certain number of profiles, but I need to total the profiles that are available per service.
I have managed to get the available profiles per account but what I really need is to total those numbers per service.
My serviceExport Controller
 public function view(): View
    {
        return view('admin.services.excel', [
            'services' => Service::all(),
            'servicesType' => Account::all(),


        ]);
    }

My Excel exportServices Blade
<h2>AVAILABEL PROFILES REPORT</h2>
@if($services->count() > 0)
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Service</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Total Profiles</th>
            <th>Profiles Used</th>
            <th>Available Profiles</th>
            <th>Date To</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach($servicesType as $account)
    <tbody>

        @php
        $used= $account->subscriptions->count();
        $total = $account->service->profiles;
        $available = $total - $used;
        @endphp

            <tr>
                <td width="20">{{ $account->service->name }}</td>
                <td width="35">{{ $account->email }}</td>
                <td width="18">{{ $account->password }}</td>
                <td width="18">{{ $total }}</td>
                <td width="18">{{ $used }}</td>
                <td width="18">{{ $available }}</td>
                <td width="20">{{ $account->dateto }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        @endforeach
    </table>
    @endif

With this I generate the following file
But what I want to get is this
But what I want to get is this
I need to total the profiles available in the accounts and group them by service.
I am not able to count the available profiles in a grouped way but I can count them individually.
Thank you very much

you should your services each by column like

    
@foreach($accounts as $account)
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Service {{$account->id}}</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Expiration</th>
            <th>Last Days</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td width="20">{{ $account->service->name }}</td>
                <td width="35">{{ $account->email }}</td>
                <td width="13">{{ $account->password }}</td>
                <td width="10">{{ $account->pais }}</td>
                <td width="20">{{ $account->dateto }}</td>
                <td width="10">{{ $account->last_days }}</td>
            </tr>
    
    </tbody>
</table>

@endforeach

